# unable to call jquery function one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

My app looks like this:

[image]

[Here is the fiddle what I tried](http://jsfiddle.net/rhy5K/3/). I want to play the next exercise time automatically on the end of the current exercise timer But currently in this fiddle its asking to click the play button for starting the new exercise timer.

Also, I want to play the 5 sounds count saying(1,2,3,4,5) just after the first audio i.e audiosource .

Here is my code:

```
function myApp($tier) { 
  this.paused = false;
  this.paused = true // set pause to true (stop)
  this.isactive = false; // countdown is active
this.timer = $tier;
  return this.observer(); // call and return the "observer" method of the "myApp" class
}

myApp.prototype.observer = function() { // observer method
  var self = this; // set this to self (this is the current instance of this class)

  $('#btn_start').on('click', function(event){ // where an user click on "btn_start"
    event.preventDefault();
    self.play('mp3'); // call the play method and store the state in a public var
    self.countdown(self.onEnd); // 30 is the audio duration - second parameter is the callback when the audio is finished
    self.isactive = true;
  });
  return this; // return this instance
};

myApp.prototype.play = function() { // play method
  var song = document.getElementById('audiosource');
  if (this.paused === true)
  {
    console.log('play song');  $("#btn_start").addClass('btn-pause'); 
    song.play(); 
    this.paused = false;

  }
  else
  { 
    console.log('pause song');$("#btn_start").removeClass('btn-pause'); 
    song.pause(); 
    this.paused = true;
  }
  return this;
};

myApp.prototype.countdown = function(callback) { // countdown method
  var self = this, // class instance
       countdown = null, // countdown
       ctx = null; // setIntervall clearer

  if (this.isactive === true) // if this method yet called
  {
    return false;
  }
  countdown = function() {
      console.log('start countdown:' + self.paused);
    if (self.timer === 0)
    {
       clearInterval(ctx);
       callback.call(this);
       return false;
    }
    if (self.paused === false) // if not in pause
    {
      self.timer -= 1;
      console.log(self.timer);
       var msec=rectime(self.timer);
      $('#timer > span').html(msec); 
    }
  };
  ctx = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
};

myApp.prototype.onEnd = function() {
   // when the audio is finish..
    $("#btn_start").removeClass('btn-pause');
    alert ('end of the first exercise, NOw lets play the second exercise for your with    another by loading its time'); 
    new myApp('10'); 
    $('#timer > span').html(rectime('10'));
};
$(function() {
 new myApp('4'); 
 $('#timer > span').html(rectime('4')); 
});



function rectime(secs) {
var hr = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
var min = Math.floor((secs - (hr * 3600))/60);
var sec = secs - (hr * 3600) - (min * 60);

while (min.length < 2) {min = '0' + min;}
while (sec.length < 2) {sec = '0' + min;}
if (hr) hr += ':';
return hr + min + ':' + sec;
 }
```

Comment: Why i am not getting any answer for this question?

Comment: You can't really expect an answer after only 3 minutes!

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Okay, why i said because there was it was `showing 15 people saw this question`. And Why   -1 vote for my question?

Comment: Because someone downvoted it perhaps?

Comment: 15 people reading the question does not imply in any way that they can or want to answer you!